# Sequential SHA 256 hashes give different outputs for the same input

Tags: python, hash, sha256, hashlib

I thought that this would be a fairly common and straightforward problem, but I searched and was not able to find it.

I am a novice Python user, mostly self-taught. I'm trying what I thought would be a fairly straightforward exercise: generating a hash value from an input phrase. Here is my code:

```
import hashlib
target = input("Give me a phrase: ").encode('utf-8')
hashed_target = hashlib.sha256(target)
print(hashed_target)
```

I execute this and get the prompt:
    Give me a phrase:

I entered the phrase "Give me liberty or give me death!" and got the hash output `0x7f8ed43d6a80`.

Just to test, I tried again with the same phrase, but got a different output: `0x7f1cc23bca80`.

I thought that was strange, so I copied the original input and pasted it in, and got a third, different hash output: `0x7f358aabea80`.

I'm sure there must be a simple explanation. I'm not getting any errors, and the code looks straightforward, but the hashes, while similar, are definitely different.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 10):

You are directly printing an object, which returns a memory address in the `__repr__` string. You need to use the `hexdigest` or `digest` methods to get the hash:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> testing=hashlib.sha256(b"sha256 is much longer than 12 hex characters")
>>> testing
<sha256 HASH object @ 0x7f31c1c64670>
>>> hashed_testing=testing.hexdigest()
>>> hashed_testing
'a0798cfd68c7463937acd7c08e5c157b7af29f3bbe9af3c30c9e62c10d388e80'
>>>
```

Comment: I think I see. When I encoded the input phrase I made it unprintable, and the output from `hashlib.sha256` is not a string or number. When I `type` it in my interpreter I get `class '_hashlib.HASH'`. The `hexdigest` method converts it back to a hex string. Is that correct?

Comment: It is not really a conversion. The hashing method returns a "sha256 HASH object" that encapsulates the resulting hash, and `hexdigest` is a getter method for the hash. The `digest` method returns the raw digest as a `bytes` object.

Comment: Many thanks. I added the `hexdigest()` method to the code and it gave the proper SHA256 output. And I learned. :)

Comment: Also, it gives the same hex value no matter how many times you perform the hashing on same string right ?